# Google Drive API for Android open EXISTING FILE

Tags: android, google-drive-api, file-permissions

I'm developing an Apps Android integrated with Google Drive. I have some problem with the opening of existing folders and files. 
In fact, when I try to open a file with DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY persimmion I can't. While with DriveFile.MODE_WRITE_ONLY I can open the file.
It's possible manage the existing files and folders in Google Drive with an Android App? Or I need some particular permissions?

Comment: Could you share some code?  Sounds like a permissions issue with your GoogleApiClient.

Comment: The connection is correct, but I can only manage the file that my app creates and I can't view and access files of my goolge drive. What code you want view? Thank you so much.